# iOS Local Notification based on date time set by user in ToDo DatePicker (Swift & SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm learning by applying and have been able to build up a todo app with title, priority and due date and pass that through core data and display it on a list view.

At this point using the following code. I've been able to launch a pop up requesting user consent for notifications.

**Function Used**

```
func requestPush() -> Void {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("All set!")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**Called in Content View using**

```
.onAppear(perform: requestPush)
```

At this point I've tried several solutions to use the date from the date picker for each todo item and set a reminder. However I am not able to get the schedule Local Notification function to work.

Here is what I've been working with so far.

```
func scheduleNotification() -> Void{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Your title"
    content.body = "Your body"
    
    var setReminder = Date()
    
    if setReminder < Date() {
        if let addedValue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: setReminder) {
            setReminder = addedValue
        }
    }
    
    let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: setReminder)
    
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: comps, repeats: false)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "alertNotificationUnique", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or guidance on how I can set up local notifications based on each todo item due date?

Note: Codes are based on various solutions available on the web. This is the one that worked for me to the point of collecting user approval for notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing the whole code and possibility to debug what exactly wrong, so I wrote small example here https://github.com/yellow-cap/swiftui-local-notifications.

The main files to explore: `LocalNotificationsApp.swift`, `NotificationManager.swift`, `ContentView.swift`

If you will have any questions, feel free to ask.

**UPDATED AFTER CODE REVIEW:**

Schedule notification action

```
    func scheduleNotification() {
        let timeIntervalMinutes = 1
        let notificationManager = // get NotificationManager
         
        // create notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Example title"
        content.body = "Example body"

        // create trigger (will show notification 1 min before selected time)
        let triggerDate = self.setReminder.addingTimeInterval(Double(-timeIntervalMinutes * 60))
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
            dateMatching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.timeZone, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: triggerDate),
            repeats: false
    )

    notificationManager.scheduleNotification(
            id: "Example id",
            content: content,
            trigger: trigger)
}
```

Notification manager scheduleNotification function:

```
    func scheduleNotification(id: String, content: UNNotificationContent, trigger: UNNotificationTrigger) {
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        notificationCenter.add(request)
}
```

Full code of the NotificationManager: https://github.com/yellow-cap/swiftui-local-notifications/blob/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/NotificationManager.swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228823/discussion-between-ares-zephyr-and-artem-chernousov).

Answer (score 1):

i suspect its not work because date comparison statement.

```
if setReminder < Date() {
        if let addedValue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: setReminder) {
            setReminder = addedValue
        }
    }
```

should be

```
var setReminder = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)    
let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: setReminder)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ernist Your suggestion was my original code as well. However, that pops up the notification after 10 seconds. I want notifications to pop up based on date set in each task as due date.

Comment: ok you just change that Date().addingTimeInterval(10)  to your task date. Notice that notification trigger date must have current datetime + 60 sec and also local notification is limited, can push 64 notification for app if lest say you have 100 task than in this case im not sure how you gonna trigger notifications.